# Sigma of 50 element sample vs sigma of the average of 5 samples of 10 elements

Tags: statistics, average, standard-deviation

I would like to understand a statement I found on a book concerning the explanation of confidence interval which is not clear to me.

We have two different situations and I would like to understand if the standard deviation is different and if it is bigger in case a or b.

`Case a)` We have 50 elements and I calculate the average ($\bar x$) and standard deviation (σ).

`Case b)` We take 5 samples of 10 elements each of the same population. We calculate $\bar x$ and σ and then from the averages and standard deviations we calculate the global $\bar x$ and σ.

The average should be the same but what about the standard deviation of the `Case b` in comparison with `Case a`? And why?

Thank you in advance for any eventual reply!

Giacomo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) Samples of size $n = 50$ from $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 60, \sigma = 7):$ We estimate $\mu$ by $A_{50} =\bar X$ and
$\sigma$ by $S_{50}^2.$

Also, $49S_{50}^2/\sigma^2 \sim \mathsf{Chisq}(\nu=49).$ Then a 95% CI for $\sigma^2$ is of the form $\left(\frac{49S_{50}^2}{U},\, \frac{49S_{50}^2}{L}\right),$ where $L=63.88$ and $U=70.22$ cut probabilities $0.025$ from the lower and upper tails, respectively, of
$\mathsf{Chisq}(\nu = 49).$ Take square roots of endpoints
to get a 95% CI for $\sigma.$

```
qchisq(c(.925,.975), 49)
[1] 63.88477 70.22241
```

(b) If you take five samples of size $n=10$ from this normal distribution you will have five variance estimates
$S_1^2, S_2^2, \dots, S_5^2.$ Then you can "pool" these
five variance estimates to get an estimate $S_p^2$ as
below:

$$S_p^2 = \frac{9S_1^2 + 9S_2^2 + \cdots + 9S_5^2}{5(9)}.$$
Then $45S_p^2/\sigma^2\sim\mathsf{Chisq}(\nu=45).$
Because the sub-sample sizes $(10)$ are all equal, $S_p^2$ is just the average of the five $S_j^2, j=1,2,3,4,5,$

Then a 95% CI for $\sigma^2$ is of the form
$\left(\frac{45Sp^2}{L},\,\frac{45Sp^2}{U}\right),$ where $L$ and $U$ are from $\mathsf{Chisq}(\nu=45).$
Again here, you can take square roots of endpoints to
get a CI for $\sigma.$

```
qchisq(c(.925,.975), 45)
[1] 59.28717 65.41016
```

In a one-factor ANOVA with five levels of the factor
and ten replications at each level, this is the
standard method of estimating the (assumed identical) $\sigma^2$ within each level. In an ANOVA, the means
of the five levels have other uses, so this method is
reasonable.

However, if you are just estimating $\sigma^2$ (or $\sigma),$ then pooling is not an efficient procedure. You have "lost" four degrees of freedom by making five
estimates of $\mu$ (from the five small-sample means)---instead of only one (from the one large sample). With fewer degrees of freedom, the CIs will tend to be longer if
you use $S_p^2$ than if you use $S_{50}^2.$

Because $S_{50}^2$ and $S_p^2$ are both unbiased estimators
of $\sigma^2 = 7^2 = 49,$ the two estimates will tend
to be about the same size. However, $S_p^2$ (based on fewer degrees of freedom) will tend to be more variable.

This is illustrated by the two simulations in R below:

One large sample:

```
set.seed(221)
m = 10^5;  v.50 = numeric(m)
for(i in 1:m) {
 v.50[i] = var(rnorm(50, 60, 7)) 
}
mean(v.50)
[1] 49.00551
var(v.50)
[1] 96.81574
sd(v.50)
[1] 9.839499
```

Five small samples:

```
set.seed(221)
m = 10^5;  v.p = numeric(m)
for(i in 1:m) {
 v.p[i] = mean(replicate(5, var(rnorm(10,60, 7)))) 
}
mean(v.p)
[1] 49.00486
var(v.p)
[1] 105.2702
sd(v.p)
[1] 10.26013
```

Finally, the title of your question may contemplate
looking at the variance of the five means of 10 observations. If the purpose is to estimate the population variance, this might be a catastrophically bad ides: These means have variance $\sigma^2/10,$ so you'd have to multiply by $10$
to estimate the population variance. Such an
estimate would be extremely variable (based on
only 4 degrees of freedom).

```
set.seed(221)
m = 10^5;  v.a = numeric(m)
for(i in 1:m) {
 v.a[i] = var(replicate(5, mean(rnorm(10,60, 7)))) 
}
mean(10*v.a)
[1] 49.01282
var(10*v.a)
[1] 1208.783
sd(10*v.a)
[1] 34.76755
```